# How to get Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields to show up on Wordpress dashboard if they were exported into PHP

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom Wordpress theme that was built by a consultant a few years ago.  The theme uses Advanced Custom Fields and Custom Post Types.  The problem is the field groups do not show up in the Wordpress dashboard.  I assume the consultant used the ACF export function to optimize load times and for source control.  I know I can edit the field groups manually, but I need to know if it is possible to 'import' these field groups back into the Wordpress ACF dashboard without the ACF JSON export file.

ACF documentation says you can hide the ACFs on the dashboard using the following function, but this function is not included in the functions.php file.

> add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', '__return_false');

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own answer on this site: [awesomeacf.com](https://awesomeacf.com/snippets/convert-an-acf-field-group-from-php-to-json/)

This process doesn't appear to work on the custom post types, but does for the field groups.